Any solution when @bind-Value and ValueChanged don't work together?
I have a Data Grid that when selecting a row, that row will be saved as an rSelect object with @bind-Value. To be able to edit the object, I @bind-Value rSelect with select, where each selection has an id value but displays a name. Now I want it to display the id and the name of the object with that id to be displayed in the MudField below. After consulting the documentation I decided to use ValueChanged but it cannot run with @bind-Value, what should I do?
<MudItem xs="6" md="6">
    <MudSelect T="string" ReadOnly="@_readonly" Dense="true" @bind-Value="@rSelect.Manvcongno" Label="ID" Variant="Variant.Outlined">
        @foreach(var nv in nhanviens)
        {
            <MudSelectItem Value="@nv.id">@nv.Name</MudSelectItem>
            
        }
    </MudSelect>
</MudItem>
<MudItem xs="6" md="6">
    <MudField Variant="Variant.Outlined" Label="Name"></MudField>
</MudItem>


@bind-Value:after exists for this purpose.  It's called after the bound value is updated.
<MudItem xs="6" md="6">
    <MudSelect T="string" ReadOnly="@_readonly" Dense="true" @bind-Value="@rSelect.Manvcongno" @bind-Value:after="this.OnAfterChanged" Label="ID" Variant="Variant.Outlined">
        @foreach(var nv in nhanviens)
        {
            <MudSelectItem Value="@nv.id">@nv.Name</MudSelectItem>
            
        }
    </MudSelect>
</MudItem>
<MudItem xs="6" md="6">
    <MudField Variant="Variant.Outlined" Label="Name"></MudField>
</MudItem>


//.....

private void OnAfterChanged()
{
    // rSelect.Manvcongno has the new value here
    // do what you want
}


I added {@bind-Value:after="this.updateNhanvien"}, and also wrote a function "public void updateNhanvien(string name){}" however I get the error "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action' ". What should I do?

Look at the OnAfterChanged signature: there's no args.  public void updateNhanvien(){}.  The bind sets rSelect.Manvcongno before calling  the after delegate. You get the value from rSelect.Manvcongno.

You can't use @bind-Value and ValueChanged together, since bind-Value uses ValueChanged aswell. Instead if you want to use ValueChanged use Value
<MudSelect T="string" Value="@rSelect.Manvcongno" ValueChanged="ManvcongnoChanged" ... >

private void ManvcongnoChanged(string? value)
{
   rSelect.Manvcongno = value;
}

But you could also bind the selected nhanvien object instead of its name
<MudSelect T="{TypeOfrSelect}" @bind-Value="@rSelect" ToStringFunc="x => x.Name">
    @foreach(var nv in nhanviens)
    {
        <MudSelectItem Value="@nv">@nv.Name</MudSelectItem>
        
    }
</MudSelect>

With ToStringFunc you can define how the selected object will be displayed.
Here's a snippet for both cases MudBlazor snippet

The relationship here is two-way, any change in either select or bind-value will affect the other. I see that your solution is only a one-way relationship. Is there any other way?
